# Access variables outside a class that extends another class

Tags: java

How can I access variable outside a class that extends an other class that is used in an array list? I get an error that says that the variable does not exist in the extended class. Take a look, I want to access the variable members without having to declare it in my Object class:

```
public abstract class Object {
    public int x, y;
}

public class House extends Object {
    public int members = 10;
}

// Somewhere else
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add( new House() );
for (Object o : list ) {
    o.members;
}
```

The problem is that in the RTS I'm writing, my Object class has over 40 variables, just because it doesn't work to declare them only in the sub class and access them from outside.
Hope you understand. How can I do this?

Comment: Don't name your class `Object`. What other classes extend `Object`? Do these classes have `members`, too?

Comment: @LutzHorn It's not really named Object in my program. Yes there are other classes that extend Object, and I also want those to be able to have their own methods and variables.

Comment: You can see my this answer if it can help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999934/get-variable-in-other-classes/16000005#16000005

This one also

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153968/proper-way-of-accessing-variable-java-android/16154388#16154388

Comment: @Er.NikhilAgrawal Your posts don't solve the problem which is about members, inheritance, and visibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `instanceof` and a cast:

```
for (Object o : list ) {
    if (o instanceof House) {
        h = (House) o;
        h.members;
    }
}
```

However, this is often considered bad design; you should consider defining an appropriate method in `Object` (which should *really* have another name, as others have pointed out) and override it in `House`. Then, you may call that method on an `Object` without knowing what kind of object it refers to, and if it is a `House`, the correct method will be called. (Learning how to do this properly, and when to do it, takes a bit of practice - google *polymorphy* and *overriding*.)

Comment: Thank you for this! So I should rather keep all my 40 variables in Object than doing it the way you proposed?

Comment: @lawls: No; keep the variables in the classes where they belong. However, one often finds that the information one needs can be acquired in a class-independent manner. Let's say that another `Object` subclass is `Car`, with a variable `int passengers`. You can define an `abstract` method in `Object` called `getOccupants()`, which you override in `House` to return `members` and in `Car` to return `passengers`. Now, you can ask for the number of occupants inside your object without knowing whether it is a `House` or a `Car`.

Comment: @lawls: (Sometimes, though, it is not possible to define such a "common" method, so judicious use of `instanceof` is allowed. For more complex scenarios, you can consider the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern); however, don't bother with it yet if you're a beginning programmer.)

Answer (score 3):

First do not name your class `Object` (see the comments). You cannot access `member` of an `Object` in your code, because Object has no field `member`, `House` has. But an `Object` does not have to be a `House`, so it is not guaranteed that it has `member`.

If you're sure that in this case youre `Object` is **always** a `House`, cast it:

```
    ((House) anObject).member;
```

This way the compiler assumes that you know more than he does about the actual class of the Object and handles it as if it was a `House`. You can use `instanceof` to check if the cast is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you understand that you are using the name for your class as 'Object', which is the parent class for all the classes in Java. Now in your environment there will be two Object classes one which java provides from java.lang.Object and another one you have created. So when you are trying to access your class object and trying to get the attributes of that, it is actually not your class object rather it is an instance of java.lang.Object and  hence you are running into an issue.

Comment: This is a very valid point, but it does not answer the question, so you should post it as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast o to a House. E.g. `((House) o).members`

Answer (score 0):

just cast the member of arraylist like this

```
((House)o).members;
```